# hyphenation with smallcaps and other formatting in bidi RTL environment

Tags: small-caps, right-to-left, bidi, emphasis

When smallcaps, bold, or italics are used for part of a hyphenated word in a right-to-left `bidi` environment, weird things happen.

The following is a MWE of what I'm noticing (compiled with XeLaTeX):

```latex
\documentclass[preview,convert]{standalone}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Scale=MatchUppercase]{Libertinus Serif}

\usepackage{bidi}

\begin{document}

\begin{LTR}
    This is all left-\textsc{to}-right, with some smallcaps.
\end{LTR}

\begin{RTL}
    This is all right-to-left.

    This \emph{should} all be right-\textsc{to}-left, but isn't.

    This \emph{should} all be right-\emph{to}-left, but isn't.

    This \emph{should} all be right-\textbf{to}-left, but isn't.
\end{RTL}

\end{document}
```

This renders as follows, with "left-to-right," appearing as "-left,toright-":

[image: rendering of the above code, with the formatted words "to" causing "left-to-right," to render as "-left,toright-"]

Note that what I'm actually trying to do involves polyglossia and some LTR text in an RTL environment, but the underlying issue appears to come from the `bidi` package.

Comment: Does the same thing happen when no font changes are involved, but just "left-to-right"?  Or, more specifically, what *is* the output with no font changes in "left-to-right"?

Comment: @barbarabeeton If I understand your question correctly, this is addressed by the first line in the RTL environment, "This is all right-to-left."  I.e., it displays as expected.  (If you're asking something else, please clarify and I'll update the question accordingly.)

Comment: I haven't used `bidi` very much, but I think you're expecting the output "right-to-left" if there are no font changes.  Is that correct, and do you get that result?

Comment: Oh.  On rereading the example, I see my question is answered.  Apologies for my inattention.

Comment: don't use the standalone class for such examples. That is a rather complicated class with various side effects. Always use article. Apart from this I would suggest to try lualatex (with babel) instead of bidi.

Comment: The result is the same with article class.  As mentioned in the question, I'm trying to use polyglossia.  I'd like to use xelatex for various reasons—is there any reason lualatex+babel is being suggested over xelatex+polyglossia?  And is there any reason that bidi shouldn't do what I'm after?

Comment: Luatex has a better direction model implementation than xetex. And if something doesn't work, your chances that it gets corrected are higher with babel and luatex.

Comment: So there's no hope of using bidirectional support and text formatting of any sort together in this way in xelatex?

Answer (score 0):

Per comments, this appears to just be a deficiency of `bidi`, and there's no hope to ever get it working right that way.

But with `lualatex` and `babel`, which do not use the `bidi` package (as opposed to `xelatex` and `polyglossia`, which do), a similar effect is obtainable.

```latex
\documentclass[preview,convert]{standalone}

\usepackage[english,bidi=basic]{babel}
\babelprovide[onchar=fonts ids]{hebrew}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Scale=MatchUppercase]{Libertinus Serif}

\begin{document}

    This is all left-\textsc{to}-right, with some smallcaps.

\begin{otherlanguage}{hebrew}
    איצט איז דא נישט קײן פראבלעם {\textdir TLT right-to-left} און דארף עס נישט זײן
    
     איצט איז דא נישט קײן פראבלעם {\textdir TLT right-\textsc{to}-left} און דארף עס נישט זײן
     
     איצט איז דא נישט קײן פראבלעם {\textdir TLT right-\emph{to}-left} און דארף עס נישט זײן

     איצט איז דא נישט קײן פראבלעם {\textdir TLT right-\textbf{to}-left} און דארף עס נישט זײן
\end{otherlanguage}

\end{document}
```

This renders as follows, which is as expected:

[image: various font styles in RTL environments rendered correctly now]

Comment: The explicit directions aren’t necessary. Without `\textdir TLT` it works.

Comment: Only because of the RTL script that was used.  If I make an RTL environment with an LTR script, it reverses the order of characters as opposed to just the order of words, so I wasn't able to reproduce the effect nicely that way.  I left the `textdir` specification in there to easily switch the example to an LTR script.